# Sending commands to projector from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send commands from my Raspberry Pi to the projector in order to control it.
Currently I have a WiFi dongle attached to the Pi so that I can SSH from my desktop and a USB to Serial connector coming out of the other USB port. I've done quite a bit of research on this and haven't found a solution that seems to work yet.

The RS232 Protocol Functions for my projector are located here: [HD25-LV](http://www.optomausa.com/webresources/files/support/2238_HD25-LV_Protocol_Function.pdf)

I have tried things such as `echo "\x7E\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x31\x0D" > /dev/ttyUSB0`
`cat /dev/ttyUSB0 \x7E\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x31\x0D`, I've tried `printf` with it as well.

I even have this Python program, but it doesn't seem to ever even establish a connection:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial('\dev\ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=5)
port.open
port.write("\x7E\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x31\x0D")
received = port.read(8)
print received # newline is printed
port.close
```

I'm not sure if there's something trivial I'm missing or what, but I seem to be unable to turn the projector on with any of these methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided in the original question will work. Totally forgot to update this, but figured it out long ago. I had the wrong adapter, thought it was null-modem but it was not so I was sending the Tx register into the Tx register rather than into Rx.

Answer (score -1):

yooooo literally are doing the same thing with the same projector as well all thats wrong is couple things:   change all "port" to "ser"

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('\dev\ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=5)

ser.open
ser.write("\x7E\x30\x30\x30\x30\x20\x31\x0D")

received = ser.read(8)
print received # newline is printed

ser.close.
```

also make sure your added to the dialout group: (from terminal) > sudo adduser (yourusername) dialout
also chmod 755 /dev/ttyUSB0

Hope that this helps thank you for posting this !! Your script worked perfect for me!!